# LINQ: How to filter collection by data in related table

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have two Entity Framework Core entities:

```
public class JobOrder {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable<JobOrderUser> JobOrderUsers { get; set; }
    }

public class JobOrderUser {
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public int JobOrderId { get; set; }
        public JobOrder JobOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The second one is a join table used for a many-to-many between the JobOrder and User tables but I don't need to drill to the User table for this.

I want to get a collection of JobOrders that have an association with a specific user. In SQL, I would write something like this:

```
select distinct
    a.*
from
    JobOrders a
    join JobOrderUser b on a.JobOrderID = b.JobOrderId
where
    b.AppUserId = someId
```

How do I do that using LINQ method syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entities are set up correctly, and their relationships are intact, you could load the `JobOrderUsers` while querying for a `JobOrder` and then filter by a user. Something like

```
JobOrder.Include(t => t.JobOrderUsers).Where(t => t.JobOrderUsers.Any(x => x.User.Id == SomeId));
```

Comment: Huh, I did try that but I wasn't getting the correct results when compared to my SQL output so I thought the technique was wrong. There may be something else going on then.

Comment: Turn on log/diagnostic and check the generated queries from your context. You can break down the LINQ into smaller parts and test each to figure out the problem. I am using similar LINQ statements all the time.

Comment: I'm at a loss but it is working now. I could have sworn I tried exactly that before when I was getting odd results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @viveknuna No, I just saw your answer when I came in this morning. I wound up going with the answer from ekh, which is what I originally attempted but though it was wrong (due to a data issue it turned out).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below query using join and `Select` the required columns data in a `jobOrdersDto` class. For that, you have to inject the `_jobOrdersRepository` and `_jobOrderUserRepository` repositories to your service where you are calling the required method.

```
var result = (from jobOrders  in _jobOrdersRepository.GetAll()
                    join jobOrderUser  in _jobOrderUserRepository.GetAll() on jobOrders.JobOrderID equals jobOrderUser.JobOrderId
                    where
                    (jobOrderUser.AppUserId == someId)
                    select new jobOrdersDto
                    {

                    }
```

**Your Service class:**

```
public class YourService
{
    private readonly IRepository<jobOrders> _jobOrdersRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<jobOrderUser> _jobOrderUserRepository;


    public YourService(
       IRepository<jobOrders> jobOrdersRepository, IRepository<jobOrderUser> jobOrderUserRepository)
       : base()
    {
        _jobOrdersRepository = jobOrdersRepository;
        _jobOrderUserRepository = jobOrderUserRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work as well and it is useful to see a version with query syntax but I'm using method syntax throughout the project.